# Negative coordiates with Tile maps

Tags: c++

How can you map negative map coordinates in a 2D tile based game?
ex. (-180,100) 
or (10, -8)

i need to access them with O(1). i don't want create a huge 2d vector and consider (500,500) as (0,0) just to call negative coordinates.

kinda of a dumb question, but i really have no clue.

Thank you.

Comment: Whats the source of those negative coordinates?

Comment: what do mean by source? map is created via an editor. user may place Tiles any she pleases. and i want access them fast, so 1D vector or a binary tree is not good enough.

Comment: "1D vector is not good enough": I am afraid there ain't anything faster than a 1D vector ! What exactly do you mean ??

Comment: by 1d i mean storing all placed tiles in a single std::vector<Tile>.

Comment: @mikbal by source I ment who inputs the numbers? If its the user, are there reasons not to "forbid" negative coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you data is dense (all or most of the points in a known 2D range are used), nothing will beat a 2D array (O(1)). Accept the coordinate shift.

If your data is sparse, how about a hash table on the coordinate pairs. Close to O(1).

Comment: data is quite sparse. i should go with hash tables. but there are so many implementations. would you recommend any one?

Comment: Can you just use the standard <hash_map> ? A possible hash function would be given by D.(x + D) + y where D is a rough estimate of the domain size. If you know the number of points in advance, it is better to preallocate.

Comment: i should use std::hash_map, since it's compatible with boost::serialization i'll make things eaiser in the long run. thank you

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you've got an infinite, procedurally-generated world, because if the world isn't infinite, it's a simple matter of setting the lower bound of the X and Y coordinate at zero, then wrapping a function around your tile map array that automatically returns zero if someone asks for a tile that's out of bounds.

In the case of an infinite world, you're not going to be able to access your tiles in O(1) time -- the best you're going to do is O(log n).  Here's how I'd go about it:

- Divide your tile map into square chunks of whatever size you find reasonable (we'll call this size S)
- Create a hash map of vectors, each vector being one chunk of your map.
- When the player moves close to a new chunk, generate it in a background thread and toss it into the hash.  The hash should be based on the x, y coordinates of the chunk (x/S, y/S).
- If you want to access a map tile at a particular position, grab t.he vector for the appropriate chunk and then access tile (x%S, y%S) in that vector.
- If you wrap this inside a class, you can add features to it, such as loading and saving chunks to disk so you don't have to hold the entire map in memory.  You can also write a getTile function that can take arbitrary coordinates, and takes care of picking the correct chunk uand position inside that chunk for you.

Your vector is always accessible in O(1) time, and the hash should be accessible in O(log n) time.  Furthermore, as long as you choose a sane chunk size, the size of your hash won't get out of hand, so the performance impact will be essentially nil.

Comment: thank you for your answer. game isnt going to be a minecraft clone. i dont need an infinite world. tile count never goes above a million.
if we experience high memory usage i will switch to boost::unordered_map with almost no syntax change.

Answer (score 0):

std::map or hash_map doesnt seem to suit my needs. they are overly complex and not flexible enough.
i decided go for std::vector and accept high memory usage

i'll leave how i did it here for future reference

```
const uint Xlimit = 500;
const uint Ylimit = 500;

class Tile
{
public:

Tile(){someGameData=NULL;}
void *someGameData;

};

class Game
{
public:

Game()
{
    tiles.resize(Xlimit, std::vector<Tile>(Ylimit, Tile()));
}

inline Tile* GetTileAtCoord(int x, int y)
{
    return &tiles[x+Xlimit][y+Ylimit];
}

protected:

std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> tiles;

};
```